# Database Model: should I store final score of students in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a database with quizzes, each having questions and options, with the corresponding correct answer.
Once, the student submits the attempted quiz, I am saving their answers in the database.

Should I store final score in the database too or like compute final score every time the request for the score is received?

Also, there is a chance that some authorized user(faculty) might have to update the "correct answer" of the quiz, in this special case the final score of student might change.

What will be the best approach? Also, do I need to use an in-memory database for handling scores?

Comment: Because (1) the number of rows is 'small', and (2) there is a chance of updating the underlying info, I agree with "calculate on the fly".  (In spite of disagreeing on that other Q&A.)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, it is better not to store the final score as there is a possibility to change the correct answer.

Or you have to re-calculate and update the student's final score whenever there is a change for "Correct Answer".